# Popup with blurred background in css3 and html

Tags: css

Hi this example shows the basic effect - click "Click here" and a popup appears over a blurred background.

http://codepen.io/Palestinian/pen/mDKkG

I tried to create a minimalist version:

http://jsfiddle.net/c2wxbey4/1/

it uses:

```
filter: blur(2px);
```

The layer is able to blur the text inside the layer but not the background text.

Comment: That's because you didn't blur it... add some CSS for `h1` or put it inside the `#layer` div. Doesn't work at all on IE by the way (not supported).

Comment: What CSS do I need to add for h1? I tried adding a color....

Comment: As Shikkediel stated, you're not blurring it, but to clarify: Your CSS is only targeting `#layer` - if you change the first line to `#layer, h1 {`, then it will target both.

Comment: Thanks well I'll just stick everything in the "#layer" div rather than use that css. http://jsfiddle.net/c2wxbey4/5/ I was assuming that the original example didn't put the background inside the blurred div.

Comment: In my webpage I had a semi-transparent layer than covered everything then had a popup window. To use blurring I guess I've got to somehow get all of the background content and stick it in a div or use the blur on the body http://jsfiddle.net/c2wxbey4/6/ If I use a blur on the body is there a way of having unblurred content? Attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/c2wxbey4/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of blurring everything except part of it...

http://jsfiddle.net/c2wxbey4/9/

```
body :not(#unblurred) {
-webkit-filter: blur(2px);
-moz-filter: blur(2px);
-o-filter: blur(2px);
-ms-filter: blur(2px);
filter: blur(2px);    
}
```

Well it doesn't work if I put content inside of #unblurred:

http://jsfiddle.net/c2wxbey4/10/

The selector to correct this is

```
body :not(#unblurred), body :not(#unblurred) * {
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
    filter: blur(2px);    
}
```

edit:
I can't get your fix to work:
http://jsfiddle.net/c2wxbey4/14/

Comment: Considering that child elements will inherit the blur, this won't work unless #unblurred is a direct child of the body.

Comment: @BramVanroy It will work if it is a descendant, even if it is not a direct child.

Comment: Good answer. Added selector for descendants of unblurred.

Comment: @vals No it won't. See this example. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/c2wxbey4/11/) it's a direct child of the body, so it doesn't inherit the filter from any element. But when it is a child of another div, [like here](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/c2wxbey4/12), the blur effect will be inherited.

Comment: @BramVanroy Sorry, my apologies. I thought that you were talking about the selector. I missed the fact that all the stacking context is blurred.

Comment: @vals No problem. Mistakes happen.

Answer (score 3):

There is another way and more cleaner way to do this using css

```css
backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
```

Here is link to an example [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajnandan/64ca53bt)

One can read more about it in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter)

Answer (score 1):

This code will blur everything except few specific div.

As you can see it's necessary to set `blur(0px);` for second div.

```css
body :not(#unblurred){
    filter: blur(2px);    
}
#unblurred #box {
    background:yellow; 
    border:2px solid black; 
    filter: blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<h1>test</h1>
<div id="unblurred"><div id="box">Test Box</div></div>
```

Comment: your answer can be improved if you try to explain what have you done...

Answer (score 0):

Add this property in body

```
filter: blur(2px);
```

Comment: Is there a way of having unblurred content on top of it? http://jsfiddle.net/c2wxbey4/7/

Comment: @LukeWenke Descendants of `body` do not inherit the filter. Therefore, you cannot override it with `filter: none` (etc.) on a descendant. I tried, didn't work. **This is a bad answer.**